# how do I solve a switch case bug in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

the question goes like this:

> Create a while loop that will execute the following code 12 times using a counter that starts at 1 and is incremented by 1 each time through the loop.
>
> Within the while loop, create a switch statement that will print out the number of days in each of the months of the year.
> Use fall-through capabilities so that you only have one print statement for all of the months that contain 31 days. Do not worry about leap years.
>
> Print out the name of the month as well. You can copy and paste your month names array from the previous lab to help make this easier.

Here is my Answer:

```
int numOfMonth = 1;
String[] months ={
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August" , "September" , "October" , "November", "December"};
int[] daysOfMonths = {28, 30, 31};

// String output;

    while(numOfMonth++ <= 12){
        int index = numOfMonth -1;

        switch(numOfMonth){
            case 2:
                System.out.println(months[index] + " has " + daysOfMonths[0] + " Days.");
                break;

            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
                System.out.println(months[index] + " has " + daysOfMonths[1] + " Days.");
                break;
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            case 12:
                System.out.println(months[index] + " has " + daysOfMonths[2] + " Days.");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

This code outputs all other values correctly except that it doesn't output january.

Please, what shall I do?

Comment: The problem is that you increment numOfMonth at the top of the loop, before you use it: `while(numOfMonth++ <= 12){...}`.  One solution is to change your "while" to a "do" loop.  Another solution is to change to `while(numOfMonth <= 12)`, and move `numOfMonth++` to the bottom of your loop.

Comment: `numOfMonth++` will increase your variable before you enter the `switch`, hence it's never `1`. Do the increment after your switch.

Comment: You can use the index variable instead. That will keep your array and switch case consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop instead of the `while` loop:

```java
for (int i=1; i <= numOfMonth; ++i) {
    int index = i - 1;

    switch (i) {
        // current switch statement
    }
}
```

The problem with the `while` loop, as written, is that the postfix will increment `numOfMonth` to 2 before the first iteration of the loop evem starts:

```
while(numOfMonth++ <= 12){
```

As a result, January will always be skipped.

Comment: The assignment seems to require a `while` specifically. In that case, a do/while might be acceptable. Or incrementing the counter in the loop body instead of the condition. Or at least offsetting the initial value by that -1 :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I disagree, and I think you're reading the code incorrectly.  The `while` loop clearly seems to be iterating over the 12 months of the year, and the `switch` statement, with its 12 condiitons seems to verify this.

Comment: Yes, twelve conditions, but the first one is skipped as you correctly noted. All three of my suggestions correct that. Example: https://pastebin.com/raw/nt50SrLt

Comment: Also not sure what exactly you disagree with.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am actually an Irish citizen, believe it or not.  Picked it up via my maternal grandmother, who was born in County Cork 100 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Move the incrementing of numOfMonth to inside of the switch statement.

```html
 while(numOfMonth <= 12){

                int index = numOfMonth - 1;

                switch(numOfMonth++){
```

Comment: Or better even after the switch.

Comment: Better still: lose "index" altogether.  The OP doesn't need both "numOfMonth" AND "index": "numOfMonth" along should suffice.  Just  1) increment at the BOTTOM of the loop (not the top), and 2) remember  that arrays are 0-based.